# how can i render template in a variable with zend framework 3?

Tags: php, rendering, zend-framework3, laminas-api-tools

I'm writing API.
Trying to render some templates,
for example index/index

config:

```
'index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/index.phtml',
```

index.phtml:

```
<span><?= $this->var ?></span>
```

I need a string as result send it to dompdf to create a pdf file, not display in the browser

code:

```
$renderer = new PhpRenderer();
$vm = new ViewModel();  
$resolver = new TemplateMapResolver();  
$resolver->setMap($this->templateMap);
$renderer->setResolver($resolver);
$template = 'index/index';
$vm->setTemplate($template);
$vm->setVariables($var);
$content = $renderer->render($vm);
```

do not generate it, and do not show any errors...
Is am I on right toward?
Where is my error?

Answer (score 0):

view/layout/index.phtml:

```
    <?php echo $this->key ?>
    <?php echo $this->value ?>
```

action controller:

```
    $view = new \Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer();
    $resolver = new \Zend\View\Resolver\TemplateMapResolver();
    $resolver->setMap(array(
        'mailTemplate' => __DIR__ . '/../../../../view/layout/index.phtml'
    ));
    $view->setResolver($resolver);

    $viewModel = new \Zend\View\Model\ViewModel();
    $viewModel->setTemplate('mailTemplate')
        ->setVariables(array(
            'key' => '1111111111111',
            'value' => '2222222222222'
        ));

    $result = $view->render($viewModel);
    echo $result;
```